# Could not find the correct Provider<SplashCubit> above this BlocBuilder<SplashCubit, SplashState> Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

Please help

This is my MyApp Class

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'Instagram',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide:
            BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2)),
      ),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide:
            BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2)),
      ),
    ),
  ),

  // here I am providing the cubit to my SplashCubit Class

  home: BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => SplashCubit()..checkSavedDetails(),
      child: const SplashScreen()),
);}}
```

this is my `SplashScreen` class

```
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
const SplashScreen({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return BlocBuilder<SplashCubit,SplashState>(
    builder: (context, state) {
  return AnimatedSplashScreen(
      duration: 3000,
      centered: true,
      splash: Image.asset('assets/images/instagram_logo.jpg'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      nextScreen: state.dataSaved
          ? HomePage()
          : LoginPage(),
});}}
```

please help, Not able to figure out what is getting wrong

I checked everything but it is giving the below error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup up MultiBlocProvider with all the Providers for your Cubits first and then make MaterialApp (and SplashScreen) a child of MultiBlocProvider. It should look something like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
  
// Add your provider for the cubit here using MultiBlocProvider
return MultiBlocProvider(
  providers: [
    BlocProvider<SplashCubit>(
      create: (context) => SplashCubit(),
      ),
  ],
  // MaterialApp (and SplashScreen) need to be a child of MultiBlocProvider
  child: MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'Instagram',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide:
            BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2)),
      ),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide:
            BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2)),
      ),
    ),
  ),

  

  home: SplashScreen()),
);

}}
```

Comment: it is not working bro, I am getting the same error again

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SplashBloc only for Splash Screen.Then you can try this

```
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(                   <-----------  add bloc provider here
      create: (context) => SplashCubit(),
      child:BlocBuilder<SplashCubit,SplashState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            return AnimatedSplashScreen(
                duration: 3000,
                centered: true,
                splash: Image.asset('assets/images/instagram_logo.jpg'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            nextScreen: state.dataSaved
            ? HomePage()
            : LoginPage(),
          });,
    );}}}
```